# Checking if a parameter is a literal string in sui move

Tags: blockchain, move-lang, sui, aptos

I want to check if a field: string::String in a struct is the exact string.

```
struct A has key, store {
    id: UID,
    field: string::String,
}

public entry fun is_field_hello(a: &A): bool {
    a.field == 'hello'
}
```

This is the compiler error I got:

```
error[E01001]: invalid character
   ┌─ .\sources\identities.move:89:20
   │
89 │         a.field == 'hello'
   │                    ^ Invalid character: '''

Failed to build Move modules: "Compilation error".
```

How can I enter a string into my codes?

Or alternatively, I can make comparison between vectors but the question then becomes how do I enter a literal vector into my codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
public entry fun is_field_hello(a: &A): bool {
    a.field == std::string::utf8(b"hello")
}
```

`b"hello"` is shorthand for a `vec<u8>[...]`, containing the string, and then `std::string::utf8` takes in a `vec<u8>` and returns a string (without checking for valid UTF8)